# Change youtube shortened url value in iframe

Tags: url, preg-replace

I am using advanced custom filed wordpress plugin to create a meta tag called youtube URL...

When some one put the video url in shorter format like this https://youtu.be/H-30B0cqh88

Then the iframe I put to show the video doesn't work cause iframe doesn't work with shorter version of url

rather it needs real url as a source.. My iframe code is as below

">

How can I achive this.. Let me show you how I want to achieve this..

I am not that expert on php so please give me the full working code..

```
<?php
the_field("listing_video_1") == $got_url_from_user_input

if $got_url_from_user_input == https://youtu.be/H-30B0cqh88 in this format

$actual_URL= replace above url to https://youtube.com/embed/H-30B0cqh88


?>
```

How can I achieve this please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to use `preg_replace` to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
<?php

// SET OUR DEFAULT URL
$got_url_from_user_input = 'https://youtu.be/H-30B0cqh88';
print "\nSTARTING URL: ".$got_url_from_user_input;

// DO THE REPLACE AND PRINT OUT THE FINAL RESULT
$actual_URL = preg_replace('~https://youtu\.be/([-A-Z0-9]+)~i', 'https://youtube.com/embed/$1', $got_url_from_user_input);
print "\nFINAL URL: ".$actual_URL;
```

There's not much magic here, so let me run down it quickly:

- `https://youtu\.be/` - Look for this pattern exactly.  We escape the dot with a backslash so it finds a literal dot and not any character.
- `([-A-Z0-9]+)` - This is just your basic character class matching any dash, letter or number, occurring at least one time.  We put it in parenthesis so that we it will be saved in `$1` and we can plug it into our final url.

Here is the above code in a working demo you can take a look at:

http://ideone.com/zECA2e

Answer (score 0):

You can just use php `str_replace()` function as in following code :

```
<?php

    $actual_url =  str_replace('https://youtu.be/', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/', $got_url_from_user_input);
    echo $actual_url;
?>
```

`str_replace()` will replace youtubes short url with embade url.